# Why is map changing my original array while iterating over?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

```
const z = [
    [
        "Almond",
        54
    ],
    [
        "Oats",
        75
    ],
    [
        "Raisins",
        undefined
    ]
]
let temp=[];
z.map((item, index) => {
    temp.push(item);
    if (item[item.length - 1] === undefined) {
      temp[index][1] = 'Not available'
    }
  });
console.log(temp)
console.log(z);
```

I'm changing the `undefined` entry to 'Not available' by creating another array.
I'm not able to understand my `z` array is changing along with `temp`.

Comment: Because temp and z both hold references to the same arrays.

Comment: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: You're also misusing `.map()`. Either use a `.forEach()` (or even better, a regular for-loop), or use `.map()` properly by returning the new element value and using the array returned by `.map()`.

Comment: `const result = z.map(([product, stock]) => [product, stock ?? "Not available"])` I assume that the second element is the stock, but if it represents something else you can rename the parameter to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to return a result array, mapping each entry in the `item` array to 'Not available' if it is `undefined` *and* then last entry in the item array.

This will leave the original z array untouched.

```js
const z = [ [ "Almond", 54 ], [ "Oats", 75 ], [ "Raisins", undefined ] ]

let result = z.map((item, index) => {
    return item.map((val, idx) =>  {
        let notAvailable = (val === undefined) && (idx === item.length -1);
        return notAvailable ? 'Not available': val;
    })
})

console.log('z:', z);
console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: And there's no duplicate for that?